# udevadm code with undefined reference error

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gcc-warning, udev

`udevadm` executes well on my desktop. However, I have written the code which links to `libudev.so`, by compiling my code with the following command:

`gcc -g -Wall -ludev test.c -o testadm`

I got a bunch of errors in the following log:

undefined reference to udev_monitor_receive_device

undefined reference to udev_device_unref

undefined reference to udev_monitor_get_fd

undefined reference to udev_monitor_get_fd

.......

I think the `libudev.so` lives in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` could already be linked well.

Please provide feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think gcc didn't find libudev. Find where it lives and pass the path to gcc with `-L` option like

```
gcc -g -Wall -L/lib/crazylibs -ludev test.c -o testadm
```

If you can't find you might missing `devel` version like `libudev-devel` (dunno your distro).

Comment: I have Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 on my desktop.
By running this gcc -g -Wall -L/lib/libudev.so.0.13.0 -ludev test.c -o testadm, I still got the same undefined reference.

Comment: In Ubuntu, I think libudev-dev equals to libudev-devel, I have also installed this onto my desktop but errors still appeared.

Comment: `-L` is **path** to your libraries, where you have to have `libudev.so`. Try to create symbolic link `libudev.so` to `libudev.so.0.13.0`. Also, /lib is default path for libraries search so you don't have to pass it with -L. Try symbolic link.

Comment: gcc -g -Wall /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0.13.0 -ludev testadm.c -o testadm <-----This is what I tried on my desktop.

Comment: Thanks AVD. I just figured out the problem. It's weird that when I use gcc 4.6, the error keeps appearing. However, When I tried gcc 4.4, it works and the executable runs well. I have no idea about why this happens but it's finally resolved. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Strange:-/ Glad to help you.